# Apache再起動失敗→SeverNameを指定しても失敗

Tags: apache

Apacheを再起動したら下記のようなエラーが出ます。

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart                                                                                   
httpd を停止中:                                            [失敗]
httpd を起動中: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified  domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
```

調べたところ、以下のサイトに解決法があり、それを参考に、
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.confに、ServerName localhost.localdomain:80を記載してみました。
http://qiita.com/pugiemonn/items/41d4bebf48437eed3f4c
↓内容。

```
#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If this is not set to valid DNS name for your host, server-generated
# redirections will not work.  See also the UseCanonicalName directive.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
# You will have to access it by its address anyway, and this will make 
# redirections work in a sensible way.
#
ServerName localhost.localdomain:80
```

しかし、結果は、

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
httpd を停止中:                                            [失敗]
httpd を起動中:                                            [失敗]
```

となり、エラーメッセージさえ出ず、失敗となります。

何がいけないのでしょうか？どうすれば再起動できるようになるでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

追記：
エラーログ​/var/log/httpd以下のエラーログを確認したところ
最後に

```
 [Mon Jul 25 11:16:01 2016] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
 httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,     using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
```

というエラーが出ていました。
以下のサイトを参考に、`/etc/logrotate.d/httpd`の

```
 postrotate
 sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
 endscript
```

をコメントアウトして、

```
 weekly
 rotate 4
 copytruncate
```

を追記してみましたが、やはりダメでした。
 http://every-rating.com/vps/httpderror-logsighup-received-attempting-to-restart.html

Comment: httpd -t で書式チェックをしてみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。

# httpd -t                                                                                                         
Syntax OK

書式は問題ないようです。

Comment: Qiitaにも書かれていますが、ServerNameに関するメッセージが出ていてもApacheは動作するので、起動できないことと直接の関係はないと思います。`/var/log/httpd/` や `/var/log/apache2/` にエラーログがあると思うので、そこを確認してみてください。（エラーログの内容を貼り付ける場合は質問を[edit]してくださいね）

Comment: 停止で失敗しています。httpdが稼働しているのに、多重に起動しようとすれば失敗するのは当然です。　まず、su /etc/init.d/httpd stopで、停止させてみてください。コマンドで停止できないなら、httpdのプロセスをkillしてから、su /etc/init.d/httpd startで起動させてみてください。

Comment: – Fumu 7さん　ご回答ありがとございます。stopしてもダメでした。そもそも起動していないようです。

Comment: – unarist♦さん　ご回答ありがとうございます。/‌​var/log/httpd/以下のエラーログを確認し、質問文の追記：以下の方法で対処を試みましたがダメでした。

Comment: `stop`で駄目だったようですが、起動していないなら`start`は試しましたか？、また、現在そのサイトは閲覧できる状態ですか？あと`/etc/init.d/httpd status`の結果が知りたいです。

Comment: – Myakuさんご回答ありがとうございます。startを試しても、質問本文と同じエラーが出て失敗となります。http://localhost.localdomain/では真っ白なページが出るのですが、hostの中に設定していたサイトは見れていたものが見れなくなっています。また、# /etc/init.d/httpd statusの結果は、
httpd status unknown due to insufficient privileges.となっています。→失礼しました。sudo実行したらhttpd は停止していますと出ました。

Comment: Syntax OKの場合は情報少ないのでトラブルシューティングが大変ですね。質問読んで OSの種類と、Apacheをどうやってインストールしたか、SSLの設定を入れてるかどうか、`ps -aef|grep httpd` `lsof -i:80` `lsof -i:443` の結果がどうなるか が気になりました。

Comment: まず、$ ip -f inet addr　とコマンドを打って、そのマシンのIPアドレスを調べてください。　そして、httpd.confには、ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 （xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxの部分は、マシンのIPアドレス）と書いてみてください。